# wordpress subdomain (probably) using the htaccess of domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

so i have a wordpress in my domain and another in subdomain (folder inside domain)

all is good now thanks to ravi here at stackoverflow. The only remaining problem is the pretty permalinks. I can't seem to use the post name but it's working when i used the default and added index.php. here's my subdomain's htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdomain/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdomain/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

...but it's not working. But it's working when i tried pasting these codes in domain's htaccess which of course, ruined the domain's permalink.

so im wondering how can i make my subdomain use it's own htaccess OR is that really my problem? Thanks in advance and here are other config.

**domain's htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule (.*) /subdomain/$1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**current permalink:** http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/%postname%/

**WordPress Address (URL):** http://subdomain.domain.com
**Site Address (URL):** http://subdomain.domain.com

*tried changing wordpress address to http://domain.com/subdomain but it doesn't help.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main domain's htaccess stop rewriting once your subdomain rule has fired.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /subdomain/$1 [L]
```

The `[L]` marks this rule as *last* and stops processing any more rules for your subdomain.